# Hydro: installation of openni_kinect

Tags: kinect, openni, ubuntu, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

My 1st attempt to install ROS Hydro + Kinect.

After:
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-desktop-full

sudo rosdep init

rosdep update

It seems that I have to install the driver for openni and kinect and that no compiled package exists for hydro. But this command:
hg clone h t t p s://kforge.ros.org/openni/drivers
tells that I can't go there ... ("Access Denied").

Could someone tell me if I'm wrong (may be, I'm a newbie :) and how to solve this.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/83311/hydro:-installation-of-openni_kinect/) by [goupil35000](https://answers.ros.org/users/7096/goupil35000/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2013-09-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should be able to apt-get install ros-hydro-openni-launch (which will include openni-camera, and any other things you need). Drivers for specific hardware are not included in desktop-full.

Kforge is slowly being decommissioned, most ROS code is now on github, and most standard drivers can be found here: https://github.com/ros-drivers

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1